# emacs can't open files outside current directory

Tags: emacs

So here is an interesting error...there is a particular folder on my desktop (hdrive, connected to a university-wide backup system, was set up automatically by IT) where emacs has difficulty opening files. In some directories within hdrive emacs can't open files above the current directory. For example,

```
cd ~/hdrive/directory/
emacs ../another_directory/file
```

gives the error message

```
emacs: `get_current_dir_name' failed: No such file or directory
```

I get the same error if instead I try

```
emacs ~/hdrive/another_directory/file
```

The files themselves are not missing and not corrupted, as using cat in place of emacs in these commands works fine. And I don't get this problem with all directories in hdrive - sometimes even a directory with this problem will have a subdirectory without it - but the directories with this problem are consistent.

There is no .dir-locals.el anywhere in hdrive, so that can't be messing things up.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `~/hdrive/directory/` a stale mountpoint?

Comment: It would be helpfull if you specified what OS you are using. That hdrive is connected to the backup system indicates that it is not a normal (say NFS) filesystem and thus may require certain special ways of accessing that the plain tools like 'cat' employs but which the internals of emacs does not.

Comment: The hdrive seems to be mounting fine. My /etc/lsb-release says I am running Ubuntu 12.04.5, although the GUI says kubuntu.

Comment: Could be a problem with something in your .emacs - you can test this if you try running emacs with the `-q` option and get the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this problem occurred because I was standing in a folder that I had deleted and recreated in another terminal (git issue).

Navigating away from the folder and back again made emacs and/or the terminal understand which folder I was actually in, and I could start emacs again with no problems.

I doubt this will solve the specific issue the questioner had, but anyone else ending up on this page through a google search on the error message might find my answer useful.